# Using rexray volume driver for AWS

Tags: docker

How do I use rexray volume driver?

I am trying to install rexray packet that I found here...

https://github.com/codedellemc/rexray

I am able to create a volume wihtout any problem.

```
# rexray volume create pg_data --size=20
ID                     Name     Status     Size
vol-0bf23b2115722476d  pg_data  available  20
```

But docker run command somehow do not see the way to use this volume.

```
# docker run -dit --name pg -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mysecretpassword --volume-driver=rexray -v pg_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data postgres
docker: Error response from daemon: chown /var/lib/libstorage/volumes/pg_data/tmp: no such file or directory.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was resolved once I upgraded the docker version.

```
Your version should support "docker plugin" command for this.
```